# Matching two values in specific element of sub-array

Tags: mongodb

I have this record:

```
  {      
    "_id" : ObjectId("5864b5d03ff9b7ad4c5eaf2f"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("967de01f640b7e4729b49fce"),
    "_children" : {
      "usersCategories" : [
        {
          "categoryId" : ObjectId("4bafbe0678081f8a40cae944"),
          "status" : "GRANTED"
        },
        {
          "categoryId" : ObjectId("0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97"),
          "status" : "APPLIED"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The rational of the record is simple: each user can have several categories attached, which can be "GRANTED" or "APPLIED".
In this case, the user applied for category `0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97` but he hasn't yet received approval.

Now, the querying. I want a list of users who match that category AND are approved for it. Also, I ALSO want to make sure that if `userId` matches a specific value (which will be set as the querier), the category is returned regardless of its status. The idea is that the record owner shouldn't have filters based on the status.

(NOTE: I realise that the following queries are wrong.)

So if user `000000000000000000000000` makes the query:

```
 { '$and': 
    [ 
      { '_children.usersCategories.categoryId': ObjectId('0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97') },
      { '$or': 
        [ 
          { '_children.usersCategories.status': 'GRANTED' },
          { userId: ObjectId('000000000000000000000000') } 
        ] 
      } 
    ] 
  }
```

If user `967de01f640b7e4729b49fce` makes the query:

```
 { '$and': 
    [ 
      { '_children.usersCategories.categoryId': ObjectId('0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97') },
      { '$or': 
        [ 
          { '_children.usersCategories.status': 'GRANTED' },
          { userId: ObjectId('967de01f640b7e4729b49fce') } 
        ] 
      } 
    ] 
  }
```

The queries can be simplified (and are still broken) taking the "owner filter" out:

```
  { '$and': 
    [ 
      { '_children.usersCategories.categoryId': ObjectId('0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97') },
      { '_children.usersCategories.status': 'GRANTED' }
    ]

  }
```

The clear problem is that that `$and` will match on the *full* record. So, it doesn't matter if `_children.usersCategories.categoryId` and `_children.usersCategories.status` find a match in two different elements of `_children.usersCategories`: the record will match.

The idea, however, is to match the subrecord *as a whole*. I realise that the simple solution is:

```
  { '$and': 
     [ 
       { '_children.usersCategories' : 
         {
           'categoryId': ObjectId('0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97'),
           'status': 'GRANTED' 
          }
        }
     ]

   }
```

Questions:

- Is this latest form the ONLY way in Mongo to make sure that all conditions will match one specific sub-element in a document?
- If it is, what about queries like: "All records that have a sub record where the ID is 0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97 and EITHER the status is `GRANTED` OR the flag `alwaysOn` is true"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [***$elemMatch***](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator to match to a first whole sub record if your okay with updating data structure to below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5864b5d03ff9b7ad4c5eaf2f"),
    "userId": ObjectId("967de01f640b7e4729b49fce"),
    "usersCategories": [{
        "categoryId": ObjectId("4bafbe0678081f8a40cae944"),
        "status": "GRANTED"
    }, {
        "categoryId": ObjectId("0d538c05c3f98b1921426d97"),
        "status": "APPLIED"
    }]
}
```

So you can use something like this:

```
db.collection.find({}, {
    'usersCategories': {
        $elemMatch: {
            'categoryId': ObjectId('4bafbe0678081f8a40cae944'),
            'status': 'GRANTED'
        }
    }
})
```

For the second part, you can try something like

```
db.collection.find({
    '$and': [{
        'usersCategories.categoryId': ObjectId('4bafbe0678081f8a40cae944'),
        {
            $or: {
                'usersCategories.status': 'GRANTED',
                'usersCategories.alwaysOn': true
            }
        }
    }]
})
```